# php MySQLi fetch results best practice

Tags: php, mysqli

These are my two methods for querying a database.

This is my first method that saves all the results in an array. Then i use a foreach loop to loop through the array.

```
public function query($query) {
            $rows = array();
            if ($result = $this->mysqli->query($query)) {
                if($result->num_rows > 1) {
                    while ($item = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $rows[] = $item;
                    }
                    //jo else sepse nxjerr error kur ska asnje  row i ben fetch kur ska row.
                } else if($result->num_rows == 1) {
                    $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();                 
                }

                return $rows;
            } else {
                echo "error";
            }
        }
```

Then to output I use:

```
$run_query = $db->query($query);
foreach ((array)$runk_query as $data) {
....
```

This is my second method:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ...");
while($run_query = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
//OUTPUT data.
....
}
```

I notice that in many cases I need to output the results so I think using the first method is bad because I use once the `while` loop and then I use again a `foreach` loop so the work is done twice but the second way is not very `OOP`.

Can anyone suggest me the best method of this or if possible another better method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can likely replace you entire first function with a call to mysqli_fetch_all() instead of iterating through each record with fetch_assoc(). This way you don't have to build your array result by result.

You can then run through all the results with your second foreach as per usual.

See: http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Alternatively if you were using PDO you could use fetchAll()

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: But is it a good way to save all the resulst in a variable using `mysqli_fetch_all();` and then use a `foreach` _loop_ to show results ? I mean isn't the job done **twice**?

Comment: You could put your processing code (your output) into another function and call it from your first function each time you retrieve from the database instead of doing a myssqli_fetch_all().